# How to prevent user saving duplicates values

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation

EDIT:

Should be only allowed in A and B field as unique values

for an example:

Valid entries are follows:

```
field A: 1
field B: 5

field A: 6
field B: 10

field A: 11
field B: 15
```

Invalid entries are:

```
field A: 1
field B: 5

field A: 5
field B: 10

field A: 1
field B: 15
```

Hope this clear out.

END

I have a data entry page where the user enters the data ranging the values from 0-23 for input `A Hourly & B Hourly`, the values that entered should be unique.

My Question:
How to prevent user saving duplicate values? throw an error message or something.

Save button:

```
<apex:commandButton value=" Save " action="{!SaveMe}" />
```

pageblockTable:

```
   <apex:pageblocktable value="{!listOfRecords}" var="r">
         <apex:column headerValue="A Hourly" headerClass="colHeadr">
<apex:input value="{!r.aHourly}" type="number" required="true" html-autofocus="true" html-min="0" html-max="23" /></div>
                </apex:column>                 
         <apex:column headerValue="B Hourly" headerClass="colHeadr">
<apex:input value="{!r.bHourly}" type="number" required="true" html-autofocus="true" html-min="0" html-max="23" /></div>
                </apex:column>
     </apex:pageblocktable>
```

Tried this [solution](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008y3SIAQ) but does not work:

```
Set<sobject> myset = new Set<sobject>();
List<sobject> result = new List<sobject>();
myset.addAll(originalList);
result.addAll(myset);
```

Comment: Should a value be only allowed in `A` field or `B` field once but be allowed in the other? Should their combination be unique? Some other interpretation? Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: Please have a look, I just updated my question.

Comment: In your example, is it a problem that there is an overlap in `A` and `B` values (5)?

Comment: @AdrianLarson: yes should not be overlap in A & B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, I'll assume you are trying to make one field unique. It should be fairly straightforward to extend the strategy.

You could do a grouping like so:

```
Map<Integer, List<SObject>> hourlyAToRecords = new Map<Integer, List<SObject>>();
for (SObject record : records)
{
    Integer key = (Integer)record.get('Field__c');
    if (!hourlyAToRecords.containsKey(key))
        hourlyAToRecords.put(key, new List<SObject>());
    hourlyAToRecords.get(key).add(record);
}
```

Now you just need to check if any of the lists have more than one record in them.

```
for (Integer key : hourlyAToRecords.keySet())
{
    List<SObject> records = hourlyAToRecords.get(key);
    if (hourlyBToRecords.containsKey(key) || records.size() > 1)
    {
        for (SObject record : records)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(
                new ApexPages.Message(
                    ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Duplicates not allowed'
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
for (Integer key : hourlyBToRecords.keySet())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: 1+, the above validations works great but there is a small change that needs to be done, the above validations does not allow if the user enters `field A=14 & B= 14` what do i need to change in order to allow if the user enter same value for that particular row?

Comment: You said in your comments *yes should not be overlap in A & B*...I can edit my answer to reflect allowing overlap, but fergodsakes man, what is it you want?

Comment: yes that's correct but i have do this small change based on the recent change :)

Comment: Just remove the `conatinsKey` check if you want to allow overlap. You could make it a little more concise because you don't need to hang onto some of the state, but sounds like it might just flip flop again.